# How to check if a string matches multiple conditions in Oracle using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle10g

After struggling with regular expressions, I've came up with this pattern `^(ABC_)\w*(_USER[0-9]*)\w*(_MOD_)\w*` that match this kind of word

If the string starts with `ABC_` and contains `_USER with any number following it`, and also contains the word `_MOD_` after that

**Example of a matching strings:**

```
ABC_sssss_USER0000000000_sssss_MOD_sssss

ABC_SCssB_USER0332_MOD_REG_SP
```

tested in this tool:
http://www.regexpal.com/

but I cant get it work in oracle sql

**Here is my testing code:**

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME,
    REGEXP_INSTR(OBJECT_NAME, '^(ABC_)\w*(_USER[0-9]*)\w*(_MOD_)\w*') AS IS_MATCH
FROM
    (

        SELECT 'ABC_SCssB_USER0332_MOD_REG_SP' OBJECT_NAME FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 'ABC_SCssB_USER0332_REG_SP' FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 'SCssB_USER0332_MOD_REG_SP' FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 'ABC_SCssB_MOD_REG_SP' FROM DUAL
    )
```

**Result:**

```
ABC_SCssB_MOD_REG_SP            0
ABC_SCssB_USER0332_MOD_REG_SP   0
ABC_SCssB_USER0332_REG_SP       0
SCssB_USER0332_MOD_REG_SP       0
```

**Expected Result:**

```
ABC_SCssB_MOD_REG_SP            0
ABC_SCssB_USER0332_MOD_REG_SP   1
ABC_SCssB_USER0332_REG_SP       0
SCssB_USER0332_MOD_REG_SP       0
```

How can I achieve that in oracle ?

Comment: Just to be clear, `_USER[0-9]*` will match `_USER` with 0 or more digits after it, thus `_USER` and `_USER1` will also be matched. If you are after digits, replace the `*` with `+`.

Comment: @npinti, I'm fine with USER with zero digits or more

Comment: I think your expected result is a bit off. `ABC_SCssB_USER0332_MOD_REG_SP` should be 1, and `ABC_SCssB_MOD_REG_SP  ` should be 0. Also, I just ran your query, verbatim, on my instance of oracle 10g and it returned 1 for `ABC_SCssB_USER0332_MOD_REG_SP` and 0 for others.

Comment: Look at [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/11cfb/1). Looks like your regex is working and matches `ABC_SCssB_USER0332_MOD_REG_SP`.

Comment: it is not working for me :\

Comment: Is it a configuration issue in my server ?

Comment: @simsim it works fine using my Oracle 10g instance, and using [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/14634/0) it works on Oracle 11g

Comment: I did once encounter regexp problems due to NLS settings, but it only affected ranges in character classes (things like [A-z]). You don't seem to have anything like that, though... try `.*` instead of `\w*` maybe?

Comment: @Timekiller, thank you, your suggestion worked, add it as an answer so that you get the credit, your answer worth up-voting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out it will work if you change `\w*` to `.*`. It's still not clear what causes `\w` to fail, though.

I have once encountered non-latin ranges in character classes (like [A-z] but for Cyrillic, [А-я]) not working properly because of NLS_SORT settings. perhaps something similar is affecting `\w`?

@simsim, please post your exact database version and NLS settings, so that we could try to get to the root of the problem and make this question more useful to others.

**EDIT:**

The reason turns out to be much simpler - database version `10.1` is the culprit, regexp support was just added in 10g and `\w` is simply not supported in this version. My instance is `10.2`, and "perl-influenced extensions" [were only added in 10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_whatsnew.htm) - see [this table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm#CHDDGICJ) for a full list of things that were added, and [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm#1006817) to see what's available in 10.1. Be aware that you also don't have support for non-greedy quantifiers (`.*?`, `.+?`) or similar character classes like `\d`.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM nls_session_parameters;` returned the following: `NLS_LANGUAGE AMERICAN`
`NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16`
And database version is `Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.1.0.5.0 - 64bi`

Comment: @simsim See the updated answer, turns out you only have limited regexp support at your disposal

Answer (score 2):

If regular expressions are not mandated you could do this, assuming you need 1 or more digits after '_USER':

```
select
    object_name,
    case when translate(OBJECT_NAME, '#0123456789', ' ##########') 
              like 'ABC\_%\_USER#%\_MOD\_%' escape '\' 
         then 1 
         else 0 
         end as is_match
from
    (
        select 'ABC_SCssB_USER0332_MOD_REG_SP' object_name from dual union
        select 'ABC_SCssB_USER0332_REG_SP' from dual union
        select 'SCssB_USER0332_MOD_REG_SP' from dual union
        select 'ABC_SCssB_MOD_REG_SP' from dual
    );
```

This runs a bit quicker than the regexp version for me (on 12.1.0.1.0) - about 75% of the time taken by the regexp version.

If there can be 0 or more digits after '_USER' then this will do:

```
select
    object_name,
    case when OBJECT_NAME like 'ABC\_%\_USER%\_MOD\_%' escape '\'
         then 1
         else 0
         end as is_match
from
    (
        select 'ABC_SCssB_USER0332_MOD_REG_SP' object_name from dual union
        select 'ABC_SCssB_USER0332_REG_SP' from dual union
        select 'SCssB_USER0332_MOD_REG_SP' from dual union
        select 'ABC_SCssB_MOD_REG_SP' from dual
    );
```

Comment: Well, I like workarounds, thanks. this will do it. but, still, its a puzzle for me why regular expression functions are not working, neither giving errors, still not finding any thing in the internet about this issue

Comment: Nice idea, and there's even no need for translate even, OP said he's fine with zero or more digits, so it's not necessary to check for them at all. I'm curious why regexp doesn't work though, something seems wrong with OP's DB config.